# How does `awk 'NF {p=1} p'` remove blank lines from the beginning and end of a file?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Searching for a way to remove blank lines from the beginning and the end (using `tac`) of a file, I've stumbled across this one:

```
awk 'NF {p=1} p'
```

How / why does this work?

I understand `NF` is only `true` if there are any fields (if the line is not a blank line).

Comment: another fun one for learning awk is `awk 'p=!p'` - try to figure out what it does and why.   or `awk '(FNR%2)'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will remove blank lines from the beginning, **but not from the end** of a file. *[Notice: this answer was witten before the [edit to the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/653844/4) that mentioned `tac`]*

It works as follows:

- `NF` is the number of fields found on the current line. If it is zero, that means the line is either empty or *blank*, i.e. contains at most whitespace (assuming the field separator is left at its default value, where any number of consecutive whitspace is considered as separator).
- The current line is printed if any condition outside of (and not associated with) rule blocks (`{ ... }`) evaluates to `true`. The flag `p` is initially uninitialized and will evaluate to `false`, so a priori nothing will be printed.
- Once a non-blank line is found (`NF` is non-zero and evaluates to `true`) the rule block `{p=1}` is entered and the flag `p` set to `1`. After that, the `p` outside the rule block evaluates to `true`, and any subsequent lines (including the current, first non-blank one) is printed.

*Notice* that since the flag `p` is never reset, any blank lines coming after the first non-blank line will be printed without filtering. If you want to remove blank lines from the end, too, a two-pass approach will be necessary:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if (NF) {if (!first) first=FNR; last=FNR} next}
     FNR>=first && FNR<=last' input.txt input.txt
```

This will process the file twice (hence it is specified twice as operand)

- In the first pass, where `FNR`, the per-file line counter is equal to `NR`, the global line counter, we identify the first and last non-blank line.
- In the second pass (`FNR` is now smaller than `NR`), we only print lines between (and including) the so identified first and last non-blank lines.

**Notice**

As stated in the [answer by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653883/377345), the two-pass approach only works with regular files. If your input is of a different nature, see the method proposed there for a solution.

Comment: Effectively, it's the same as `awk NF,0` or `sed '/[^[:blank:]]/,$!d'`

Answer (score 6):

Using this technique to remove blank lines from both the head and tail of the file:

```bsh
awk 'NF {p=1} p' file | # remove blank lines at the file head
  tac |                 # reverse the lines
  awk 'NF {p=1} p' |    # remove blanks from the "new head"
  tac |                 # re-reverse the file
  sponge file           # from the `moreutils` package, to overwrite the file
```

Comment: Or, as noted by @Stéphane Chazelas, `awk 'NF,0' file | tac | awk 'NF,0' | tac`

Answer (score 5):

What your code does and why it only deletes blank lines at the start of the input has already been explained in [@AdminBee's answer](/a/653848) for instance, but here for completeness, I'll suggest an alternative method for removing both leading and trailing blank lines without having to make two passes on the file (which would only work for regular files and not arbitrary input).

```
awk '
       NF {print saved $0; saved = ""; started = 1; next}
  started {saved = saved $0 ORS}' < file
```

Where we delay the printing of blanks lines up to the next non-blank line we see afterwards (provided we've already seen at least one non-blank line before).

Answer (score 5):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`:

```
awk -v RS='^\\s*\n|\n\\s*$' '$0!=""'
```

For example:

```
$ cat file


foo
bar
```

```
$ awk -v RS='^\\s*\n|\n\\s*$' '$0!=""' file
foo
bar
```

The above sets the record separator to blank lines (including lines that only contain space chars) at the start of the input or blank lines at the end of the input and just prints what's in between. The `$0!=""` is necessary because if there are blank lines at the start of the file then that'll match `^\s*\n` and so awk will understand there to be an empty record before that appearance of a RS.

wrt `awk 'NF {p=1} p'` and `How / why does this work?` from your question - to be clear, it doesn't work. It'll only remove blank lines from the beginning of a file, not from the end of a file. It sets a flag (poorly named `p` for `print` instead of `f` for `found` or similar) the first time a non-empty line is found and only prints when `p` is true thereby not printing anything before that first non-empty line.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't mind clobbering any spaces or tabs on the blank lines that you want to keep, this will remove blank lines from beginning & end:

```
awk 'NF{for(;c;--c)print "";print;x=1;next} x{++c}'
```

It counts how many blank lines occur between non blank lines, and prints that many empty lines before each non blank line.

Answer (score 2):

We can delete both the leading and trailing empty lines by means of the following POSIX-ly sed code. The leading empty lines are deleted by means of the range operator, which is triggered only when it sees an nonempty line. For the trailing lines, we start accumulating empty lines till we either see an eof (wherein we promptly delete this bunch of trailing empty lines) or hit an nonempty line (wherein we print this bunch of atleast one empty + exactly one nonempty line).

```
sed -e '
  /./,/^$/!d
  /./b
  :a
    $d;N
  /\n$/ba
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

sample file

```
foo = 1700; goo = 1800
pravee

ajay
koy
ram
```

Empty lines at 1,4,8

Since we need to delete empty lines at first line and last line

a. first we find last occurence of empty line using below command and assign to variable

```
lastemptyline=$(awk '/^$/{x=$0}END{print NR}' file)
```

b. then we will use sed command to delete first and last line

```
sed -i -e "1{/^$/d}" -e "$lastemptyline{/^$/d}" file
```

output

```
foo = 1700; goo = 1800
pravee
    
ajay
koy
ram
```

Comment: `awk '/^$/{x=$0}END{print NR}' file` will print the number of lines in the input file. It's [almost] equivalent to `wc -l  < file`. I think you meant `awk '/^$/{x=NR}END{print x+0}'`. As always with your answers though - you do not need sed when you are using awk.